# Pointer to a different instance.

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

How can such a code work correctly when the `IWindow` pointer clearly has an address to a `ISheet` class which has no method `Say`?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class IWindow
{
private:
    int p;
    double f;
public: 
    void Say() { cout << "Say in IWindow"; }
};

class ISheet
{
public:
    void foo() { cout << "ISheet::foo"; }
};

int main()
{
    ISheet *sh = new ISheet();
    int ptr = (int)sh;
    IWindow *w = (IWindow*)ptr;
    w->Say();
    sh->foo();

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled in Visual Studio 2015 it runs and executes with no problems, but I was expecting to get an error on line `w->Say()`. How is this possible?

Comment: Undefined behavior. The code happens to run correctly by mere coincidence (BTW, that depends on your definition of "correctly", since what you will effectively get is the printout of the other function). But the language standard does not generally permits this (i.e., every compiler can handle it in a different manner, hence the undefined behavior). In any case, once you perform that "unauthorized" cast from `ISheet` to `IWindow`, anything can happen.

Answer (score 5):

It works by the grace of the almighty Undefined Behavior. Your functions don't try to access any data members of the containing class, they just write something to `std::cout`, which anyone can do.

What you've effectively done is

```
#include <iostream>

void IWindow_Say(void*)
{
    std::cout << "Say in IWindow";
}

int main()
{
    IWindow_Say(0xdeadbeef);  // good luck with that pointer
}
```

You never used the pointer (which became `this` in your original example) so no side-effects were observed.